# Program to glue together html files, text and imgs

Tags: python, html

So let's say I have a few HTML files like header.html, body1.html, body2.html, somethingsomething.html, footer.html. One text file and a few images that are supposed to be glued inside those HTML. Before I start writing my own python script just wanted to ask if you guys know any program that does that or framework that could help me.

Comment: What do you mean for 'glued inside'

Comment: I mean that inside the html file there is a field <p class="g-color-white">** place where the part of the text file is supposed to go**</p>

Comment: That can be solved by simple python - like 'NORMAL' python

Comment: I know, just wanted to know if there is something similar already out there.

Comment: Might not be helpful, but 'Beautifulsoup' might be helpful - it's a python module

Comment: I actually seems like it can help a lot. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use flask or django framework for merge all html files inside the single html file, like in case of flask app the normal way is to create normal template as layout and inside that you can add templates and create custom html page like 
[Template inheritance in jinja templating.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/templateinheritance/)